# Homogeneous linear second order ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following DE

$$u''(p)-R(p)u'(p)+S(p)u(p)=0,$$

with

$$R(p)=-2C\frac{b}{a}p\;+\;\frac{-2\frac{b}{a}+4p}{\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\frac{b}{a}p+2p^2},\\
S(p)=2C^2\frac{k^2}{a^2}\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\frac{b}{a}p+2p^2\right).$$

The constants $a$, $k$ and $C$ are real positive numbers while $b$ can be any real number.

I have tried to apply Laplace transform, but doesn't simplify the problem, and I dont know any other method. I wonder if someone could indicate a way of reducing the order of the equation or a more direct method for getting an analytical solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maple finds rather complicated "closed-form" solutions involving hypergeometric functions:

$$u \left( p \right) =c_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{1/2\,{\frac {C \left( -\sqrt {b+2
\,k}\sqrt {b-2\,k}{b}^{2}+ \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k
 \right)  \left( pa-b \right)  \right) p \left( -\sqrt {b+2\,k}\sqrt {
b-2\,k}+b \right) }{{a}^{2} \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k
 \right) }}}} \left(  \left( -1/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2}
 \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}+b \left( C{b}^{3}{k}^{2}-2\,Cb{k}
^{4}-1/2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{3}{k}^{2} \right)  \right)  \left( a{
b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2} \right) 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(-1/2\,{\frac {C{b}^{4}{k}^{2}-2\,C{b}^{2}{k}^{4}-1/2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}+2\,{a}^{3}b{k}^{2}-5/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}};\,3/2;\,{\frac {C \left( a{b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}})}
+1/2\, \left( \sqrt {b+2\,k} \left( a{b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2}
 \right) \sqrt {b-2\,k}+abp \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k
 \right)  \right)  \left( b+2\,k \right)  \left( b-2\,k \right) 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(-1/2\,{\frac {C{b}^{4}{k}^{2}-2\,C{b}^{2}{k}^{4}-1/2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}+2\,{a}^{3}b{k}^{2}-1/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}};\,1/2;\,{\frac {C \left( a{b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}})}
{a}^{3} \right) +c_{{2}}{{\rm e}^{1/2\,{\frac {C \left( -\sqrt {b+2\,k
}\sqrt {b-2\,k}{b}^{2}+ \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k \right) 
 \left( pa-b \right)  \right) p \left( -\sqrt {b+2\,k}\sqrt {b-2\,k}+b
 \right) }{{a}^{2} \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k \right) }}}}
 \left(  \left( -3/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k
 \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}+ \left(  \left( -1/2\,{b}^{2}+2\,{k}^{2}
 \right) {a}^{3}+Cb{k}^{2} \left( {b}^{2}-2\,{k}^{2} \right)  \right) 
b \right) C \left(  \left( {b}^{2}p-4\,{k}^{2}p \right) a+2\,b{k}^{2}
 \right) ^{2}
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(-1/2\,{\frac {C{b}^{4}{k}^{2}-2\,C{b}^{2}{k}^{4}-1/2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}+2\,{a}^{3}b{k}^{2}-7/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}};\,5/2;\,{\frac {C \left( a{b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}})}
+3/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right)  \left( b-2\,k \right) 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(-1/2\,{\frac {C{b}^{4}{k}^{2}-2\,C{b}^{2}{k}^{4}-1/2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}+2\,{a}^{3}b{k}^{2}-3/2\, \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}};\,3/2;\,{\frac {C \left( a{b}^{2}p-4\,a{k}^{2}p+2\,b{k}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{ \left( b+2\,k \right) ^{3/2} \left( b-2\,k \right) ^{3/2}{a}^{3}}})}
 \left( C \left(  \left( {b}^{2}p-4\,{k}^{2}p \right) a+2\,b{k}^{2}
 \right) ^{2}\sqrt {b+2\,k}\sqrt {b-2\,k}+ \left(  \left( -{b}^{2}+4\,
{k}^{2} \right) {a}^{2}+Cb{p}^{2} \left( b-2\,k \right)  \left( b+2\,k
 \right) a+2\,C{b}^{2}{k}^{2}p \right)  \left( b+2\,k \right)  \left( 
b-2\,k \right) a \right) {a}^{3} \right)
$$